# shortenning angular code to one method

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui

how can I shorten my code so I dont have to use two different methods to do a file upload for two different fields

this is what I have

```
            <input type="file" name="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uF1(this.files)"/>

            <input type="file" name="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uF2(this.files)"/>
```

here is controller

```
 $scope.upF1 = function(files) {

                    var fd = new FormData();
                    //Take the first selected file
                    fd.append("file", files[0]);
                    //console.log(files);
                    $http.post('/url', fd, {
                        withCredentials: true,
                        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined },
                        transformRequest: angular.identity
                    }).success( function(data){
                        $scope.image1 = data[0]['imageFileName'];
                    });

                };

                $scope.uF2 = function(files) {

                    var fd = new FormData();
                    //Take the first selected file
                    fd.append("file", files[0]);
                    //console.log(files);
                    $http.post('/url', fd, {
                        withCredentials: true,
                        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined },
                        transformRequest: angular.identity
                    }).success( function(data){
                        $scope.image2 = data[0]['imageFileName'];
                    });

                };
```

you can see that I am trying to set up  $scope.image1  and  $scope.image2

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<input type="file" name="file" onchange="uf(this.files,image1)"/>
<input type="file" name="file" onchange="uf(this.files,image2)"/>
```

and

```
$scope.uf = function(files,imageNumber) {

                    var fd = new FormData();
                    //Take the first selected file
                    fd.append("file", files[0]);
                    //console.log(files);
                    $http.post('/url', fd, {
                        withCredentials: true,
                        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined },
                        transformRequest: angular.identity
                    }).success( function(data){
                        $scope[imageNumber] = data[0]['imageFileName'];
                    });

                };
```